# How to increase gaps between vertical gridlines in chartjs

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

[image]

I have drawn a chart using Chartjs for a large number of datasets. So, there are many vertical gridlines by default which looks pathetic. I want to increase the gap between the vertical lines.

Any help will be appriciated.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the `maxTicksLimit`, this will make it so only that amount of ticks will get rendered which in turn makes the distance between ticks larger

code:

```
options: {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [
      {
        ticks: {
          maxTicksLimit: 10
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Source: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html

Answer (score 2):

Good answer from @LeeLenalee

I would like to add an additional option for fine-tuning in case of y-Axis (horizontal gridlines):

Chart.js **v3.2.0**

If you want to achieve a minimalistic design with even **less gridlines** (say only 2 or 3 gridlines for basic orientation), chart would tend to not take advantage of full chart height for little maxTicksLimits (no automatic scaling, see example with **maxTicksLimit: 3**)

Here are examples (y-Axis) to demonstrate:

- **Normal** (no ticks-costumization)

  ```
   options: {
      scales: {
        y: {
           ticks: {
              // no costumization
              }
           }
        }
     }
  ```

  [image]

  (Many gridlines and ticks, but automatic scaling working)
- **maxTicksLimit: 10**

  ```
   options: {
      scales: {
        y: {
           ticks: {
              maxTicksLimit: 10
              }
           }
        }
     }
  ```

  [image]

  (Less gridlines and ticks, automatic scaling still OK)
- **maxTicksLimit: 3**

  ```
    options: {
       scales: {
         y: {
            ticks: {
               maxTicksLimit: 3
               }
            }
         }
      }
  ```

  [image]

  (Does not take advantage of full chart height, no automatic scaling)
- **callback**

  ```
    options: {
       scales: {
         y: {
            ticks: {
               callback: function(value, index, values) {
                  let step = 5;

                  //values[0].value is first tick (tick_min)
                  //values[values.length-1].value is last tick (tick_max)

                  //tick_max - tick_min is range of values at y-Axis

                  if (values[values.length-1].value - values[0].value > 15) {
                     //define condition (> 15) and
                     //step size (10) according to your estimated data range
                     step = 10;
                  } else {
                     step = 5;
                  };
                  if (Number.isInteger(value/step)) {
                     return value;
                  } else {
                     return '';
                  }
                 }
               },
               grid: {  //hide gridlines where there is no tick
                  z: 1,
                  color: function(context) {
                     if (context.tick.label != '')  {
                        return 'rgba(61,138,254,0.5)';
                     } else {
                        return 'rgba(61,138,254,0)'; //transparent
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
  ```

  [image]

  (Few gridlines **and** automatic scaling OK)

  Source: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats